# how can I translate my SQL statement to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to LINQ and understand little enough to do some simple LINQ. But now, what I have is more complex than what I can do. I have created the SQL statement, tried it and it works. But I can't translate it to LINQ.

**EDIT:** I tried to code the linq and created a model to show it to a view.  However, I'm not getting the data I want. I can't figure out where did I get the linq wrong. Please help.

[This are the tables involved, the output using SQL and output using LINQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOh7g.jpg)

This is the SQL:

```
  select oh.date, oh.id, 
         od.TotalAmount, 
         CASE when oh.Discount_level = 2
            then ((od.TotalAmount / 1.12) * .2)
         END as Discount, 
         (od.TotalAmount / 1.12) as VATSale, 
         ((od.TotalAmount / 1.12) * .12) as VAT,
         CASE when oh.Discount_level = 2
            then ((od.TotalAmount / 1.12) * .8)
            when oh.Discount_level = 1
            then od.TotalAmount
         END as AmountDue
  from Order_Header oh
  inner join 
  ( 
    select Order_Header_id, SUM(price * quantity) as TotalAmount
    from Order_Details
    group by Order_Header_id
  ) od
  on oh.id = od.Order_Header_id;
```

The linq I have:

```
  var list = (from oh in db.Order_Header
                 join iq in (
                                from t in db.Order_Details
                                group t by t.Order_Header_id
                                into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    ohId = g.Key,
                                    totalAmount = ((from t2 in db.Order_Details select t2.price * t2.quantity)).Max()
                                }
                             )
                 on oh.id equals iq.ohId
                 select new Report
                 {
                     date = oh.date,
                     ohId = iq.ohId,
                     totalAmount = iq.totalAmount,
                     discount = oh.Discount_level == 2 ? (iq.totalAmount /1.12) * 2 : 0 ,
                     VATSale = iq.totalAmount / 1.12,
                     VAT = (iq.totalAmount / 1.12) * .12,
                     amountDue = oh.Discount_level == 2 ? ((iq.totalAmount / 1.12) * .8) * 2 : iq.totalAmount
                 }).ToList();
```

The Report model:

```
public class Report
{
    public DateTime? date  { get; set;  }

    public int ohId  { get; set;  }

    public double totalAmount { get; set; }

    public double discount { get; set; }

    public double VATSale { get; set; }

    public double VAT { get; set; }

    public double amountDue { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far to do this with LINQ. Any effort at all would be good.

Comment: hmm, interesting, it will involve at least two projections (`.Select`). well, some people need to see your effort before indulging in such query. and just a bit of clue, you can put inline conditions in linq - the legendary `<condition> ? <if_pass> : <otherwise>`, e.g. `.Select(x => x.DiscountLevel == 2 ? ((x.TotalAmount / 1.12) * 0.8) : ....)`.

Comment: also, it'd be helpful if you post the structure of `Order_Header` and `Order_Details`.

Comment: Yes, I just uploaded a photo of the tables.

Comment: well, while i'm drafting my answer. lol. happy coding anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your POCO models looked like these:

```
    public class Order_Header
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Discount_Level { get; set; }
        public Order_Detail Order_Detail {get;set;}
    }

    public class Order_Detail
    {
        public Guid Order_Header_Id { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Order_Header Order_Header { get; set; }
    }
```

and let `ods` as a `IDbSet<Order_Detail>` instance within a `DbContext`.
You can translate your query above into Lambda LINQ like this.

```
    var odproj = ods.GroupBy(x => x.Order_Header_Id)
                    .Select(x => new { Order_Header = x.First().Order_Header,
                                       TotalAmount = x.Sum(y => y.Price * y.Quantity)})
                    .Select(x => new { Order_Header = x.Order_Header,
                                       Id = x.Order_Header.Id,
                                       TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                                       Discount = (x.Order_Header.Discount_Level == 2 ? ((x.TotalAmount / 1.12) * 0.2) : 0),
                                       VATSale = (x.TotalAmount / 1.12),
                                       VAT = ((x.TotalAmount / 1.12) * 0.12),
                                       AmountDue = ((x.Order_Header.Discount_Level == 2) ? ((x.TotalAmount / 1.12) * 0.8)
                                                                                         : (x.Order_Header.Discount_Level == 1 ? x.TotalAmount : 0)
                                                   )
                     });
```

**Explanation**
First, we group the `Order_Detail` (many) based on `Order_Header` (one) to define a single transaction (in POS system sense thats it). After grouping, we 'calculate' the total amount based on price and quantity of the orders. The total price calculation is done in the first `Select`, it generates an anonymous class with 2 field, one to keep the `Order_Header` information and the other one the one we want. The next `Select` we compute the discount, VATSale, etc -- your complex if-else in the first clause.

Ps. I have not tried this in EF yet, my RAM just too small to kick up SQL Server. Take this idea with grain and salt. The key corner of this problem, which i'm a bit hesitant is whether EF will recognize `Order_Header = x.First().Order_Header` or not. Nevertheless, using the LINQ is bad enough to guarantee you with heavy `OUTER JOIN` that might end up make your query dropped by SQL Execution Planner. If its too complex, just make a `STORED PROCEDURE` and pull up an `edmx` to map it (wait, does Code First can do this? I do wonder).

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Can I ask you another thing, if you don't mind? What if I want to have parameters? Like, `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I just realised that there will be time that I want to get the rows in a specific span of date.

Comment: hmm, better to dig stackoverflow a bit.. i think someone have asked it. if it doesn't, please ask it in another question and be specific on the field type. Happy coding nevertheless.